# How can I skip the credits?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

The credits in Assassin's Creed games take approximately 4000 years to finish. How can I skip the credits?

Comment: wow, that must mean by Dad may be as old as the Face of Boe, considering he has to complete the entire series each time a new game comes out or i get new DLC for just one of them (ie. GotY Edition of AC2's included DLC)

Answer (score 5):

During the credits in this game there are some cutscenes to watch, and there's also a sequence where you can control the Jackdaw while listening to a dialogue with one of his family members.

That being said, for the first time in AC history, by popular request, you **can skip the credits!!** Just hold the regular cutscene skip button. Remember, you can only do this after watching both the aforementioned cutscenes (i.e. the background is black). Tested on PC and Xbox One

Comment: What button would that be on PC? Does it work at any point during the credits, including the dialogue bit?

Comment: I think it's E, the same as any other cutscene, and it should work at any point

Comment: Wish I had known this last night when I watched for 15 minutes before finally trying to hit something and saw the "Hold to skip cutscene button." Blah.

Comment: The PC key to skip the credits seems to be S, though I've discovered it far too late to judge whether it's possible to skip at any point.

Answer (score 2):

In Assassin's Creed IV, you can skip the credits. In PC, hold S to skip  credits (E is used to skip other cinematic).

Answer (score 1):

In Assassin's Creed 4 you hold S or space+s to skip the credits.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither S nor E but the down arrow key. If you press some random buttons (I'd suggest pressing every button) on keyboard, the game shows a message in the lower right corner, in mine it showed hold down arrow key.

Comment: Did you rebind movement from WASD to arrow keys?

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there is no way whatsoever to skip the credits on any Assassin's Creed game.